# Why is parameters in my function not working?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I want my function to print out the initials of each of the names. Eg: LeBron James would print LJ.

```
def names(first, last):
    firstLetter = first[0]
    secondLetter = last[0]
    print(firstLetter + secondLetter)
names(LeBron, James)
names(Michael, Jordan)
names(Steph, Curry)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant for your inputs to be strings!

```
names("LeBron", "James")
names("Michael", "Jordan")
names("Steph", "Curry")
```

The way you have it, Python is interpreting the parameters you pass in (ex. `names(LeBron, James)`) as variables, but you don't have any variables that correspond to those names.

Answer (score 0):

Just now python thinking that Lebron e.t.c is variables. Fix:

```
names("LeBron", "James")
names("Michael", "Jordan")
names("Steph", "Curry")
```